# Using single XSLT -multiple Transformation for removal of xsi:nil ="true" and splitting of XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, talend

**We are trying to write XML file using data integration tool (talend) ) 
then,We triggered tXSLT (that is transformation component) over outputted XML.
Basically, we want to apply two transformation at a time.
that is**

**splitting of XML file 
and removal of xsi:nil ="true" element from our XML document.**

**Original XML file Look like**

It has SalesOrders information

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>

<SalesOrders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlfilename.xsd">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <CustomerPoNumber>22195175</CustomerPoNumber>
      <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      <NewCustomerPoNumber xsi:nil="true"></NewCustomerPoNumber>
      <Supplier xsi:nil="true"></Supplier>
      <Customer>027885</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-02-12</OrderDate>
      <InvoiceTerms xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceTerms>
      <Currency xsi:nil="true"></Currency>
      <ShippingInstrs xsi:nil="true"></ShippingInstrs>
      <CustomerName>STAGE STORES DIST CTR 00601</CustomerName>
      <ShipAddress1 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress1>
      <ShipAddress2 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress2>
      <ShipAddress3 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress3>
      <ShipAddress4 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress4>
      <ShipAddress5 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress5>
      <ShipPostalCode xsi:nil="true"></ShipPostalCode>
      <Email xsi:nil="true"></Email>
      <OrderDiscPercent1 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent1>
      <OrderDiscPercent2 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent2>
      <OrderDiscPercent3 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent3>
      <Warehouse xsi:nil="true"></Warehouse>
      <SpecialInstrs xsi:nil="true"></SpecialInstrs>
      <SalesOrder xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrder>
      <OrderType xsi:nil="true"></OrderType>
      <MultiShipCode xsi:nil="true"></MultiShipCode>
      <ShipAddressPerLine xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddressPerLine>
      <AlternateReference xsi:nil="true"></AlternateReference>
      <Salesperson xsi:nil="true"></Salesperson>
      <Branch xsi:nil="true"></Branch>
      <Area xsi:nil="true"></Area>
      <RequestedShipDate xsi:nil="true"></RequestedShipDate>
      <InvoiceNumberEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceNumberEntered>
      <InvoiceDateEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceDateEntered>
      <OrderComments xsi:nil="true"></OrderComments>
      <Nationality xsi:nil="true"></Nationality>
      <DeliveryTerms xsi:nil="true"></DeliveryTerms>
      <TransactionNature xsi:nil="true"></TransactionNature>
      <TransportMode xsi:nil="true"></TransportMode>
      <ProcessFlag xsi:nil="true"></ProcessFlag>
      <TaxExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptNumber>
      <TaxExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptionStatus>
      <GstExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptNumber>
      <GstExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptionStatus>
      <CompanyTaxNumber xsi:nil="true"></CompanyTaxNumber>
      <CancelReasonCode xsi:nil="true"></CancelReasonCode>
      <DocumentFormat xsi:nil="true"></DocumentFormat>
      <State xsi:nil="true"></State>
      <CountyZip xsi:nil="true"></CountyZip>
      <City xsi:nil="true"></City>
      <InvoiceWholeOrderOnly xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceWholeOrderOnly>
      <SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction>
      <SalesOrderPromoSelectAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoSelectAction>
      <GlobalTradePromotionCodes xsi:nil="true"></GlobalTradePromotionCodes>
      <eSignature xsi:nil="true"></eSignature>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-380804</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderHeader>
      <CustomerPoNumber>22195175</CustomerPoNumber>
      <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      <NewCustomerPoNumber xsi:nil="true"></NewCustomerPoNumber>
      <Supplier xsi:nil="true"></Supplier>
      <Customer>027885</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-02-12</OrderDate>
      <InvoiceTerms xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceTerms>
      <Currency xsi:nil="true"></Currency>
      <ShippingInstrs xsi:nil="true"></ShippingInstrs>
      <CustomerName>STAGE STORES DIST CTR 00601</CustomerName>
      <ShipAddress1 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress1>
      <ShipAddress2 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress2>
      <ShipAddress3 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress3>
      <ShipAddress4 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress4>
      <ShipAddress5 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress5>
      <ShipPostalCode xsi:nil="true"></ShipPostalCode>
      <Email xsi:nil="true"></Email>
      <OrderDiscPercent1 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent1>
      <OrderDiscPercent2 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent2>
      <OrderDiscPercent3 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent3>
      <Warehouse xsi:nil="true"></Warehouse>
      <SpecialInstrs xsi:nil="true"></SpecialInstrs>
      <SalesOrder xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrder>
      <OrderType xsi:nil="true"></OrderType>
      <MultiShipCode xsi:nil="true"></MultiShipCode>
      <ShipAddressPerLine xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddressPerLine>
      <AlternateReference xsi:nil="true"></AlternateReference>
      <Salesperson xsi:nil="true"></Salesperson>
      <Branch xsi:nil="true"></Branch>
      <Area xsi:nil="true"></Area>
      <RequestedShipDate xsi:nil="true"></RequestedShipDate>
      <InvoiceNumberEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceNumberEntered>
      <InvoiceDateEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceDateEntered>
      <OrderComments xsi:nil="true"></OrderComments>
      <Nationality xsi:nil="true"></Nationality>
      <DeliveryTerms xsi:nil="true"></DeliveryTerms>
      <TransactionNature xsi:nil="true"></TransactionNature>
      <TransportMode xsi:nil="true"></TransportMode>
      <ProcessFlag xsi:nil="true"></ProcessFlag>
      <TaxExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptNumber>
      <TaxExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptionStatus>
      <GstExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptNumber>
      <GstExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptionStatus>
      <CompanyTaxNumber xsi:nil="true"></CompanyTaxNumber>
      <CancelReasonCode xsi:nil="true"></CancelReasonCode>
      <DocumentFormat xsi:nil="true"></DocumentFormat>
      <State xsi:nil="true"></State>
      <CountyZip xsi:nil="true"></CountyZip>
      <City xsi:nil="true"></City>
      <InvoiceWholeOrderOnly xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceWholeOrderOnly>
      <SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction>
      <SalesOrderPromoSelectAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoSelectAction>
      <GlobalTradePromotionCodes xsi:nil="true"></GlobalTradePromotionCodes>
      <eSignature xsi:nil="true"></eSignature>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-380801</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderHeader>
      <CustomerPoNumber>22193037</CustomerPoNumber>
      <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      <NewCustomerPoNumber xsi:nil="true"></NewCustomerPoNumber>
      <Supplier xsi:nil="true"></Supplier>
      <Customer>027886</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-02-11</OrderDate>
      <InvoiceTerms xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceTerms>
      <Currency xsi:nil="true"></Currency>
      <ShippingInstrs xsi:nil="true"></ShippingInstrs>
      <CustomerName>STAGE STORES DIST CTR 05099</CustomerName>
      <ShipAddress1 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress1>
      <ShipAddress2 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress2>
      <ShipAddress3 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress3>
      <ShipAddress4 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress4>
      <ShipAddress5 xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddress5>
      <ShipPostalCode xsi:nil="true"></ShipPostalCode>
      <Email xsi:nil="true"></Email>
      <OrderDiscPercent1 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent1>
      <OrderDiscPercent2 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent2>
      <OrderDiscPercent3 xsi:nil="true"></OrderDiscPercent3>
      <Warehouse xsi:nil="true"></Warehouse>
      <SpecialInstrs xsi:nil="true"></SpecialInstrs>
      <SalesOrder xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrder>
      <OrderType xsi:nil="true"></OrderType>
      <MultiShipCode xsi:nil="true"></MultiShipCode>
      <ShipAddressPerLine xsi:nil="true"></ShipAddressPerLine>
      <AlternateReference xsi:nil="true"></AlternateReference>
      <Salesperson xsi:nil="true"></Salesperson>
      <Branch xsi:nil="true"></Branch>
      <Area xsi:nil="true"></Area>
      <RequestedShipDate xsi:nil="true"></RequestedShipDate>
      <InvoiceNumberEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceNumberEntered>
      <InvoiceDateEntered xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceDateEntered>
      <OrderComments xsi:nil="true"></OrderComments>
      <Nationality xsi:nil="true"></Nationality>
      <DeliveryTerms xsi:nil="true"></DeliveryTerms>
      <TransactionNature xsi:nil="true"></TransactionNature>
      <TransportMode xsi:nil="true"></TransportMode>
      <ProcessFlag xsi:nil="true"></ProcessFlag>
      <TaxExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptNumber>
      <TaxExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></TaxExemptionStatus>
      <GstExemptNumber xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptNumber>
      <GstExemptionStatus xsi:nil="true"></GstExemptionStatus>
      <CompanyTaxNumber xsi:nil="true"></CompanyTaxNumber>
      <CancelReasonCode xsi:nil="true"></CancelReasonCode>
      <DocumentFormat xsi:nil="true"></DocumentFormat>
      <State xsi:nil="true"></State>
      <CountyZip xsi:nil="true"></CountyZip>
      <City xsi:nil="true"></City>
      <InvoiceWholeOrderOnly xsi:nil="true"></InvoiceWholeOrderOnly>
      <SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction>
      <SalesOrderPromoSelectAction xsi:nil="true"></SalesOrderPromoSelectAction>
      <GlobalTradePromotionCodes xsi:nil="true"></GlobalTradePromotionCodes>
      <eSignature xsi:nil="true"></eSignature>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-380813</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
        <LineCancelCode xsi:nil="true"></LineCancelCode>
        <StockCode>JBLC-SMH-16OZ-01</StockCode>
        <StockDescription>SMH JAMAICAN LI COND. 16OZ</StockDescription>
        <Warehouse xsi:nil="true"></Warehouse>
        <CustomersPartNumber xsi:nil="true"></CustomersPartNumber>
        <OrderQty>3.0</OrderQty>
        <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
        <Price>7.14</Price>
        <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
        <PriceCode xsi:nil="true"></PriceCode>
        <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
        <Units xsi:nil="true"></Units>
        <Pieces xsi:nil="true"></Pieces>
        <ProductClass xsi:nil="true"></ProductClass>
        <LineDiscPercent1 xsi:nil="true"></LineDiscPercent1>
        <LineDiscPercent2 xsi:nil="true"></LineDiscPercent2>
        <LineDiscPercent3 xsi:nil="true"></LineDiscPercent3>
        <AlwaysUseDiscountEntered xsi:nil="true"></AlwaysUseDiscountEntered>
        <CustRequestDate xsi:nil="true"></CustRequestDate>
        <CommissionCode xsi:nil="true"></CommissionCode>
        <LineShipDate xsi:nil="true"></LineShipDate>
        <LineDiscValue xsi:nil="true"></LineDiscValue>
        <LineDiscValFlag xsi:nil="true"></LineDiscValFlag>
        <OverrideCalculatedDiscount xsi:nil="true"></OverrideCalculatedDiscount>
        <UserDefined>18</UserDefined>
        <NonStockedLine xsi:nil="true"></NonStockedLine>
        <NsProductClass xsi:nil="true"></NsProductClass>
        <NsUnitCost xsi:nil="true"></NsUnitCost>
        <UnitMass xsi:nil="true"></UnitMass>
        <UnitVolume xsi:nil="true"></UnitVolume>
        <StockTaxCode xsi:nil="true"></StockTaxCode>
        <StockNotTaxable xsi:nil="true"></StockNotTaxable>
        <StockFstCode xsi:nil="true"></StockFstCode>
        <StockNotFstTaxable xsi:nil="true"></StockNotFstTaxable>
        <AllocationAction xsi:nil="true"></AllocationAction>
        <ConfigPrintInv xsi:nil="true"></ConfigPrintInv>
        <ConfigPrintDel xsi:nil="true"></ConfigPrintDel>
        <ConfigPrintAck xsi:nil="true"></ConfigPrintAck>
        <TariffCode xsi:nil="true"></TariffCode>
        <LineMultiShipCode xsi:nil="true"></LineMultiShipCode>
        <SupplementaryUnitsFactor xsi:nil="true"></SupplementaryUnitsFactor>
        <ReserveStock xsi:nil="true"></ReserveStock>
        <ReserveStockRequestAllocs xsi:nil="true"></ReserveStockRequestAllocs>
        <TradePromotionCodes xsi:nil="true"></TradePromotionCodes>
      </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

**We tried 
following xslt stylesheet on it :**
**

It tells about two template at at time. But when i am applying both at same time
it is not working fo us. it only split the  XML but did not remove xsi:nil ="true" element from Original XML.
but when i am applying on seperate basis it removes the tag xsi:nil ="true" from documents.

**Here is description of  XSL file**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output encoding="Windows-1252"/>
<xsl:template match="*/@*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">
            <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml">
                <SalesOrders>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </SalesOrders>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**

**OutPut of each splitted XML should look like after split and removal of xsi:nil**

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>

<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlfilename.XSD">
<Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <CustomerPoNumber>C1000</CustomerPoNumber>
      <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      <NewCustomerPoNumber/>
      <Supplier/>
      <Customer>000010</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2006-11-04</OrderDate>
      <InvoiceTerms>0</InvoiceTerms>
      <Currency>$</Currency>
      <ShippingInstrs>Ship via Hong Kong</ShippingInstrs>
      <CustomerName>The SYSPRO Outdoors Company</CustomerName>
      <ShipAddress1>This is the alternate delivery address 1</ShipAddress1>
      <ShipAddress2>This is the alternate delivery address 2</ShipAddress2>
      <ShipAddress3>This is the alternate delivery address 3</ShipAddress3>
      <ShipAddress4>This is the alternate delivery address 4</ShipAddress4>
      <ShipAddress5>This is the alternate delivery address 5</ShipAddress5>
      <ShipPostalCode>90210</ShipPostalCode>
      <Email>Sender001@Sender001.com</Email>
      <OrderDiscPercent1>2.50</OrderDiscPercent1>
      <OrderDiscPercent2>1.50</OrderDiscPercent2>
      <OrderDiscPercent3>1.00</OrderDiscPercent3>
      <Warehouse>E</Warehouse>
      <SpecialInstrs>Handle with care</SpecialInstrs>
      <SalesOrder>221124</SalesOrder>
      <OrderType>1</OrderType>
      <MultiShipCode/>
      <ShipAddressPerLine/>
      <AlternateReference/>
      <Salesperson>100</Salesperson>
      <Branch/>
      <Area/>
      <RequestedShipDate>2006-12-20</RequestedShipDate>
      <InvoiceNumberEntered/>
      <InvoiceDateEntered/>
      <OrderComments/>
      <Nationality/>
      <DeliveryTerms/>
      <TransactionNature/>
      <TransportMode/>
      <ProcessFlag/>
      <TaxExemptNumber/>
      <TaxExemptionStatus/>
      <GstExemptNumber/>
      <GstExemptionStatus/>
      <CompanyTaxNumber/>
      <CancelReasonCode/>
      <DocumentFormat/>
      <State/>
      <CountyZip/>
      <City/>
      <InvoiceWholeOrderOnly/>
      <SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction>W</SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction>
      <SalesOrderPromoSelectAction>A</SalesOrderPromoSelectAction>
      <GlobalTradePromotionCodes>GLACC,GLFREE</GlobalTradePromotionCodes>
      <eSignature/>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <CustomerPoLine>1</CustomerPoLine>
        <LineActionType>A</LineActionType>
        <LineCancelCode/>
        <StockCode>B100</StockCode>
        <StockDescription>Bicycle</StockDescription>
        <Warehouse>FG</Warehouse>
        <CustomersPartNumber>FF334221</CustomersPartNumber>
        <OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
        <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
        <Price>400</Price>
        <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
        <PriceCode/>
        <AlwaysUsePriceEntered/>
        <Units/>
        <Pieces/>
        <ProductClass/>
        <LineDiscPercent1>0.5</LineDiscPercent1>
        <LineDiscPercent2>0</LineDiscPercent2>
        <LineDiscPercent3>0</LineDiscPercent3>
        <AlwaysUseDiscountEntered>N</AlwaysUseDiscountEntered>
        <CustRequestDate>2006-12-20</CustRequestDate>
        <CommissionCode/>
        <LineShipDate/>
        <LineDiscValue>0</LineDiscValue>
        <LineDiscValFlag/>
        <OverrideCalculatedDiscount/>
        <UserDefined>USER</UserDefined>
        <NonStockedLine/>
        <NsProductClass>NSPR</NsProductClass>
        <NsUnitCost/>
        <UnitMass/>
        <UnitVolume/>
        <StockTaxCode/>
        <StockNotTaxable/>
        <StockFstCode/>
        <StockNotFstTaxable/>
        <AllocationAction/>
        <ConfigPrintInv/>
        <ConfigPrintDel/>
        <ConfigPrintAck/>
        <TariffCode/>
        <LineMultiShipCode/>
        <SupplementaryUnitsFactor/>
        <ReserveStock/>
        <ReserveStockRequestAllocs/>
        <TradePromotionCodes>BIKEACCR,FREE1</TradePromotionCodes>
      </StockLine>
   </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>**
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated.

**Thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It tells about two template at at time. But when i am applying both at
>   same time it is not working fo us. it only split the XML but did not
>   remove xsi:nil ="true" element from Original XML.

That's because your first two templates are never applied. Your last template, the one matching the root `/` node, is the first one to be executed - and this template does not contain any `xsl:apply-templates` instructions.

If you change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
```

you will get the expected result.

---

P.S. Note that your first template:

```
<xsl:template match="*/@*"/>
```

will remove **all** attributes, not only the `xsi:nil ="true"` ones as stated in your question. To make it work *exactly* as stated, it needs to be changed to:

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

---

### Added:

> Problem is after splitting the file namespace prefix situated at
>   `<Orders xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`; instead of
>   `<SalesOrders>` root element

To avoid this, change:

```
<xsl:copy>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
```

To summarize, your stylesheet should look like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">
        <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml">
            <SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlfilename.XSD">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </SalesOrders>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added 2:

IMHO, the splitting you show us does **not** work correctly as you claim. But that should be subject for another question.

Comment: When i applied exactly same instruction  my output becomes <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<SalesOrders> 22195175 A 027885 2016-02-12 STAGE STORES DIST CTR 00601 ORD-380804 9999 JBLC-SMH-16OZ-01 SMH JAMAICAN LI COND. 16OZ 3.0 EA 7.14 EA Y 18 </SalesOrders> which is  diffrent from desired one.

Comment: @vickps There is obviously something wrong with your implementation. You can see how it works (albeit in a single result document) here: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYj3

Comment: @Micheal We wanted to split files also  and want to remove<Orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  and after  implementing this suggested   way. We are not getting desired result.

Comment: @ Micheal -Linga solution work for me  only  the Problem  is after splitting the file  namespace prefix situated at <Orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> instead of <SalesOrders> root element.

Comment: @vickps **1.** I cannot demonstrate split files in an online tool.  **2.** Why is this a problem? It's a redundant namespace declaration. It  should make no difference to the receiving application.

Comment: We are going to apply this stylesheet into my environment. and we will get back to you shortly after implementation.Thanks  for giving me your valuable time.We appreciate it.

Comment: @Micheal Those added stylesheet is perfect for me. and Yes it is giving me correct Output. Again Thanks for your valuable time on this.

Comment: @Micheal As i am new comer here  please could you tell me How  do i accept  answer ! When i am trying for it. it says 15 reputation needed.

Comment: @Micheal I gone through given link. My vote will become public after gaining 15+ repo.

Comment: @vickps You are confusing voting with accepting. You (and only you) can accept an answer to your own question, without any limitations.

Comment: @Micheal  <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml"> We have  to append customer name  string, xml column that is SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-380804</SalesForceOrderNumber> . Our output rename reflect as SORTOIDOC_ORD-380804. Please guide me.

Comment: @Micheal : I am  trying to apply Your XSLT transformation here http://paste.ofcode.org/HNRXQd8j3Z34iSbmarFhiX

Comment: But  Not able to Implement XSLT transformation  :  I am trying to Implement this XSLT transformation : http://paste.ofcode.org/wu54DCNSRAT3hQCtTVWpY5

Comment: getting Output as : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  only one line in after XSLT transformation.  Please could you help me out . here we are just repeating Item NODE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output encoding="Windows-1252"/>

    <!-- remove attribute templates -->
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="removeAttr">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="removeAttr"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ************** -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="phase1" as="node()+">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="removeAttr"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="$phase1/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">
            <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml">
                <SalesOrders>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </SalesOrders>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. Here, you create a temporary variable `phase1`, transform the document into it by removing the attributes(check the `mode` attribute on templates and apply-templates to apply the desired templates).
2. Then again transform the variable to get the splitting done.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working like charm. We just implemented in our environment and yes , Getting desired outcome.

Comment: But we just saw that splitting across group by OrderHeader falls in each splitted xml file . For ex: 3 rows  each having Order Header should fall one time in one xml. when i applied above transformation 3 OrderHeader falls in  each  xml file which is incorrect for me.

Comment: Could you please provide sample outputs here? I do not have context of your grouping logic here. And, which field are you grouping `OrderHeader` by here?; using `CustomerPoNumber`??

Comment: we would like to output each row  as <SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlfilename.XSD">
<Orders>
<OrderHeader>
</OrderHeader>
<OrderDetails>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>

Comment: Can you please explain more on what you want to do with each `OrderHeader`? I can't figure out anything from your previous comment.

Comment: Basically we want to  split xml in a way each xml should consist of  one OrderHeader and corresponding OrderDetail ONLY.

Comment: Dear @vickps, I may not understand Orders here. You got to help me out. How do I know which OrderDetail belongs to which OrderHeader?? Are there repeating OrderHeaders? If yes, what do you do with them?

Comment: We have attached  output of  each  splitted xml   how should it look like after transformation on it. please let me know if any query on it.

Comment: Here ,we want to capture  one orders per file. each orders made up of orderHeader and OrderDetails. Lets say  file1.xml should have one order that is ONE orderHeader with OrderDetails. similarly , File2.xml should  have ONE orderHeader with OrderDetails. in this way, suppose we have 10 Orders so split should be across Orders. exactly 10 Orders  XML file should be generated after applying  XSL  transformation.

Comment: Our split should be  : One Order Per xml file.

Comment: Your input XML has only 1 `OrderDetails`, should it repeat for every file?

Comment: And how the person trying to help you should know when it is going to repeat and when it's not?? Please go through this link [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you may rephrase the question with all the necessary information.

Comment: We would like to go through the how-to-ask page and reframe it. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Hi Linga we are trying to sort out issue. only issue remains is namespace prefix is appearing additional in Orders. that is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: We do not want  Namespace prefix in Orders Element Instead Just wanted to be in root element that is SalesOrder.

Comment: Please try with adding the attribute, `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"`, to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml"> We have  to append customer name  string, xml column that is SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-380804</SalesForceOrderNumber> . Our output rename reflect as SORTOIDOC_ORD-380804. Please guide me.

Comment: Hi @vickps.. your problem isn't very clear. Can you post a new question and add the link to the question here.

Comment: Ok i will post here my new post  i got answer  of my question here

Comment: Here is link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269726/how-do-i-append-input-xml-attribute-into-name-of-multiple-output-xml-file-using/36276309#36276309

Comment: Input XML 
I am trying to apply Your XSLT transformation  in this XML paste.ofcode.org/HNRXQd8j3Z34iSbmarFhiX

Comment: But Not able to Implement XSLT transformation : I am trying to Implement this XSLT transformation : paste.ofcode.org/wu54DCNSRAT3hQCtTVWpY5

Comment: getting Output as : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> only one line in after XSLT transformation. Please could you help me out . here we are just repeating Item NODE

Comment: Any help on it would be much appreciated !

Comment: We also have :The key element specifies an attribute or element value as a key (unique, non-nullable, and always present)