# How do i append input xml attribute into name of multiple output xml file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

We have following input xml file in which we are trying XSLT processing instructions.

** Complete Input XML file :**

It consist of Loop element as StockLineItem.for every single OrderHeader and OrderDetails we can have many StockineItems. Document tells single SalesforceOrderNumber element only. Hence We have to Output this element with xml Filename on each XML write.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber/>
         <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
         <NewCustomerPoNumber/>
         <Supplier/>
         <Customer>005352</Customer>
         <OrderDate>2016-03-28</OrderDate>
         <InvoiceTerms/>
         <Currency/>
         <ShippingInstrs/>
         <CustomerName>TARGET DC0594</CustomerName>
         <ShipAddress1/>
         <ShipAddress2/>
         <ShipAddress3/>
         <ShipAddress4/>
         <ShipAddress5/>
         <ShipPostalCode/>
         <Email/>
         <OrderDiscPercent1/>
         <OrderDiscPercent2/>
         <OrderDiscPercent3/>
         <Warehouse/>
         <SpecialInstrs/>
         <SalesOrder/>
         <OrderType/>
         <MultiShipCode/>
         <ShipAddressPerLine/>
         <AlternateReference/>
         <Salesperson/>
         <Branch/>
         <Area/>
         <RequestedShipDate/>
         <InvoiceNumberEntered/>
         <InvoiceDateEntered/>
         <OrderComments/>
         <Nationality/>
         <DeliveryTerms/>
         <TransactionNature/>
         <TransportMode/>
         <ProcessFlag/>
         <TaxExemptNumber/>
         <TaxExemptionStatus/>
         <GstExemptNumber/>
         <GstExemptionStatus/>
         <CompanyTaxNumber/>
         <CancelReasonCode/>
         <DocumentFormat/>
         <State/>
         <CountyZip/>
         <City/>
         <InvoiceWholeOrderOnly/>
         <SalesOrderPromoQualifyAction/>
         <SalesOrderPromoSelectAction/>
         <GlobalTradePromotionCodes/>
         <eSignature/>
         <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-374881</SalesForceOrderNumber>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <LineCancelCode/>
            <StockCode>ABSO-NHO-5OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>NHO AFRICAN BLACK SOAP 5OZ</StockDescription>
            <Warehouse/>
            <CustomersPartNumber/>
            <OrderQty>3.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>56.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <PriceCode/>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <Units/>
            <Pieces/>
            <ProductClass/>
            <LineDiscPercent1/>
            <LineDiscPercent2/>
            <LineDiscPercent3/>
            <AlwaysUseDiscountEntered/>
            <CustRequestDate/>
            <CommissionCode/>
            <LineShipDate/>
            <LineDiscValue/>
            <LineDiscValFlag/>
            <OverrideCalculatedDiscount/>
            <UserDefined>1</UserDefined>
            <NonStockedLine/>
            <NsProductClass/>
            <NsUnitCost/>
            <UnitMass/>
            <UnitVolume/>
            <StockTaxCode/>
            <StockNotTaxable/>
            <StockFstCode/>
            <StockNotFstTaxable/>
            <AllocationAction/>
            <ConfigPrintInv/>
            <ConfigPrintDel/>
            <ConfigPrintAck/>
            <TariffCode/>
            <LineMultiShipCode/>
            <SupplementaryUnitsFactor/>
            <ReserveStock/>
            <ReserveStockRequestAllocs/>
            <TradePromotionCodes/>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

**We tried XSLT transformation on it.**

```
XSLT2.0

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">
        <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC{position()}.xml">
            <SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xmlfilename.XSD">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </SalesOrders>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The Output after transformation result:**
that is
Splitting in this manner
SORTOIDOC1.XML
SORTOIDOC2.XML
SORTOICDOC3.XML

**Output we are trying for**

```
SORTOIDOC_SalesForceOrderNumber
```

**FOR EX: SORTOIDOC_ORD-380804.XML instead of SORTOIDOC1.XML**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811096/using-single-xslt-multiple-transformation-for-removal-of-xsinil-true-and-sp shows that there can be several `SalesForceOrderNumber` in each group - so which one would you want to use?

Comment: @Michael : In my previous question  loop element were Order Header but  here  it is no more looping element. loop element is shifted to stockLineItem. and OrderHeader points to single element SalesForceOrderNumber. So we can utilize field SalesForceOrderNumber because  while doing integration  with Salesforce it  should be unique in nature.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow - please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Michael Please bear with me ,I am going to post  Complete Example of  output XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Output we are trying for**
>
> `SORTOIDOC_SalesForceOrderNumber`

Since the context element is `Orders`, you can use the following relative path to get the corresponding `SalesForceOrderNumber` element :

```
<xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC_{OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber}.xml">
```

Comment: Great Thanks to You ! We just tried  the same you mentioned in our XSLT processing instruction and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position()` use `SalesForceOrderNumber`.

Comment: Sorry, But it did not work for me. it gives me  output as SORTOIDOC.XML as output filename. We want to Output as SORTOIDOC_SalesForceOrderNumber.XML.